# Using vectors as input to dataframe

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

Sorry I couldn't find a better title, I'll try to make my question a bit clearer:

```
# my input:
test_character<- 'name1'
conditions<- c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
#
#My line
myDF<- data.frame(test_character, conditions)
```

What I get is a dataframe with 2 columns, one of which is `test_character` (repeated in 3 rows) and the other is `conditions`.
What I want is a single row with 4 columns. Please advise ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mydf <- data.frame(test_character, t(conditions))
```